# BootstrapVue - hover on buttons with tailwind

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, tailwind-css

I have a code like below:

```
          <router-link to="/auth/register">
            <b-button pill class="uppercase text-sm bg-green-500 hover:bg-red-500 border-none">Get Started</b-button>
          </router-link>
```

with using bootstrap-vue and tailwind, i try to create a button with hover effect, on hover my button must be in `bg-red-500` color, but it not work and my button on hover is still in gray color, can somebody tell me what i have doing wrong?

thanks for any helps

Comment: It should work.  Can you show package.json?  Maybe it's a version issue